# How can I resolve the typing error when accessing a function property?

Tags: typescript

I have a `foo` function, and within that function, I want to call the `prop` function if it exists.

In regular JavaScript, I can set the prop outside the function without any issues.

However, TypeScript throws an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"prop"' can't be used to index type '() => void'.
```

```
function foo() {
  if (foo['prop']) {
    foo['prop'].some();
  }
}

// foo['prop'] = null;
// foo['prop'] = { some: () => {} };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxGYRNFOAbQHIAHAJzmsoF0s8CCyq6HmA6AZzgBbAKaYA3PkQBfXLNwB6BclRd6jJogC8iMCAA2+yUpUUa65tpyJBogFwksWgHw5pMyUA)

I've tried using `if ('prop' in foo && foo['prop'])`, but it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this typing error?

Comment: [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) applies to _unions_. You have to give the compiler some reason to believe that could be a property, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/N5koBW. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface or type for the object foo that includes the 'prop' property.

```
interface Foo {
  prop?: () => void;
}

function foo() {
  const fooObject: Foo = {
    prop: () => {
      // implement 'some' function
    }
  };

  if (fooObject.prop) {
    fooObject.prop();
  }
}
```